# Strange behavior on page reload in ASP.NET using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I'm working on an ASP.NET project and I found a strange behavior: some pages (I haven't tested all), when updating, don't go through the controller.

For example: we know that a page, when loaded, passes through the `Index` method of its controller, however, I noticed that the controller is only being invoked the 2nd time that the user refreshes the page. In fact, not only the 2nd time, but every even time. And in odd times, the controller's Index is never invoked.

Is this common ASP.NET behavior? Or is it something that is happening due to some design specification? I will not share any code snippets because I don't even know where the problem might be.

Comment: Do you have a `Cache-Control` / `Last-Modified` / `ETag` header? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching